# Laravel - Two or more alias to same table in query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to replicate a `SQL` query in Laravel with query builder, but i don't know how to define more than one alias to he same table.

I have this `SQL` query working fine.

```
select b.url as url, b.id as id
from item a, item b
where a.type = 'big'
AND a.published = 1
AND b.parent_id = a.id
AND b.published = 1
```

This is the Laravel try:

```
$query = DB::table('item as a, item as b');
$query->where('a.type', '=', 'big');
$query->where('a.published', '=', 1);
$query->where('b.parent_id', '=', 'a.id');
$query->where('b.published', '=', 1);
```

I also try with:

```
$query = DB::table('item');
$query->fromRaw('item a, item b');
$query->where('a.type', '=', 'big');
$query->where('a.published', '=', 1);
$query->where('b.parent_id', '=', 'a.id');
$query->where('b.published', '=', 1);
```

I need to use the query builder because i need some conditionals in the next steps, thats why i cant use a simple 'hasMany' relationship.

Update with `items` table details:

[image: Items table]

Comment: you mean 'item1 as a' and 'item2 as b'. Right?

Comment: Hm, why would you need two aliases on the same table?

Comment: Please put your table structure. maybe need to use join function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**#Raw Expressions**

Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query. These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points! To create a raw expression, you may use the `DB::raw` method:

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions

```
$query = DB::table(DB::raw('item as a, item as b'))
              ->where('a.type', '=', 'big')
              ->where('a.published','=',1)
              ->where('b.parent_id','=', DB::raw('a.id'))
              ->select('b.url','b.id')
              ->get();
```

Comment: I guess you need fix `->where('b.parent_id','=',DB::raw('a.id'))`